# pdf_tex file not found

Tags: graphics, errors, inkscape

I'm trying to include an image (edited in Inkscape) in my document.
However, everytime I run the file , it says "File not found".

In Inkscape i have saved the document as .pdf and used the latex option as 
given by: http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/inkscape-images-with-latex-fonts/

I have tried:

- export area as page
- export area as drawing,

to find out if that may be the problem, but error still persist.

Both the .pdf as .pdf_tex file are in the same file as my .tex file.

**Note**: The example image (given in link above), also in the same file as my .tex file, works perfectly.

This is the code i'm using:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\def\svgwidth{200pt}
\input{drawing4.pdf_tex}
\caption{Double pendulum}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the error message that keeps showing up:

[image]

I am using Texmaker and Inkscape 0.48

Any help will be much appreciated

Kind regards,

Andrew

---

**EXTRA**:

So I think i should add this to give a little more insight into the problem.

This is the image i want to include in my document. The graph I copied it from another document using sniptool and paste it in Inkscape. I want to give it a header and add the symbols underneath so it can have the same font as my tex document. You know, to have a nice and uniform document.

When I draw some random figures in Inkscape and include text such as MoS$_2$ and export it to pdf+LaTeX, it work perfect.

I think it has something to do with editing this image.

What I added was: the text in the top and bottom and the blue numbers

**Question reformulation:**
Can I edit a photo/image (adding text, arrows etc) in Inkscape and export it to pdf+latex and have it work perfectly?

Thank you in advance!
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to include the example picture in the above mentioned link? http://www.howtotex.com/download/inkscape-howtotex.zip with `\input{drawing.pdf_tex}` instead of `\input{drawing4.pdf_tex}`

Comment: The error message doesn't say "file not found" but "file ended while scanning ...". This means something is wrong with the content of the file. It sounds like a missing brace.

Comment: Yes @samcarter, I have tried to include the example picture in the above link, works perfectly. 

I think the problem how Inkscape saves my image as pdf+LaTex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I wish I could figure out what is wrong with the content of the file and know where to add that missing brace.
The whole day I have been trying, all possible ways with no luck.

Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:**

The "extra info" shows a percent sign in the label text: `MoS$_2%--WS$_2$`. The unprotected percent sign act as comment char, the rest of the line is ignored by TeX and leaves the `\put` that sets the label unfinished. A percent sign can be generated by `\%` in TeX, but I think it is just a typo and a `$` sign is intended to close the math for the subscript: `MoS$_2$--WS$_2$`.

**Older analysis:**

Your `drawing4.pdf_tex` is broken, truncated inside the arguments of a `\put` command, the correct error message is:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \put.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9 \input{drawing4.pdf_tex}

?
```

A `.pdf_tex` file is basically:

```
\begingroup
  % some settings
  \begin{picture}(1,...)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{drawing4.pdf}}%
    \put(...,...){...}
    ...
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup
```

The following file

```
\begingroup
\begin{picture}(1,1)  
\put(0,
```

generates the same errors as `drawing4.pdf_tex`.

The inkscape export has failed, try again, possible reasons:

- Inkscape export: Bug/error/abnormal abortion.
- Disk full.
- ...

Comment: Well I tried about 20x already (not exaggerating). The procedure for exporting is straight forward, and was done exactly as mentioned in the link above. 

I added extra info to the problem, so maybe that may give more insight. 

Thank you for your effort Heiko Oberdiek

Comment: @Andrew: The extra info was indeed helpful and has shown a percent sign in the label text, see the updated answer.

Comment: The % sign was my issue as well. Thanks for adding the update to your answer!